# How does Docker handle concurrency on database when many containers are using the same database basic image?

Tags: database, oracle, docker, concurrency

I mean, if it works to save time, hence I read that you can do test running on parallel on several containers over the same basic image of an APP, saving in the container only the changes, then how does it work with DB concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

When multiple containers are run from a given base image, they each work on their own "copy" of the image so there will be no concurrency issue as each container is it's own database.

See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#the-copy-on-write-cow-strategy) for more information.

Comment: So, thought that one of the main things of Docker was to use less and more efficiently the hardware. As you say it, I suppose you'll need either a lot of disk or memory space. Anyways, thanks for your answer and link.